# Single column plot in r versus gnuplot

Tags: r, split-plot, gnuplot

I am new to R environment. I have created a simple data set as shown below.

```
1  
2  
3  
7  
8  
9
```

I simply plotted this data using both gnuplot and R.

Command to plot in gnuplot

`plot "test.dat" u 1 w l;`   Here is the plot

[image]
I had already loaded the contents by `mydata<-read.table("test.dat")`
But when I plot the same data in r using `plot(mydata)` I get the following plot.

[image]

How to get the plot I got in gnuplot in R too?

Multi-column plot in gnuplot.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to reproduce the plot in R:

```
# the data
mydata <- data.frame(c(1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9))

# the plot    
plot(seq(nrow(mydata)) - 1, mydata[[1]], type = "l", col = "red")
```

The values in the first column of `mydata` are plotted as a function of their indices (starting at 0).

[image]

---

If your dataset has multiple columns, you can use this approach:

```
# an example data frame
mydata <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9),
                     b = c(1, 4, 7, 8, 10, 13),
                     c = c(2, 5, 9, 12, 13, 15))

# range of the values
rg <- range(mydata)

# plot
plot(x = seq(nrow(mydata)) - 1, col = NA, ylim = rg)
for (i in seq(mydata)) {
  lines(mydata[[i]], col = i)
}
legend(x = "topright", col = seq(mydata), lty = 1,
       legend = names(mydata))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sven! But suppose I have a bigger practical data set of thousands of records. Then how to avoid the manual typing in the 1st line and directly use the data file ?

Comment: @Soumajit What is your goal? Different lines for the columns?

Comment: Yes Sven. Gradually I would like use multi column data set and analyse them independently by different plots.

Comment: @Soumajit You want a different plot for each column?

Comment: @Soumajit Of course you can use `read.table`. I didn't because I don't have access to your files. Hence, you don't need to specify the data by hand.

Comment: Sven I would need plot similar to the 3rd plot from gnuplot in r as well.

Comment: @Soumajit See the update.